How to loop over a list of extensions to check that files of each type exist?
I have the following directory structure:
main_dir/
│   ├── randstr1.randstr2.tar.gz
│   ├── randstr3.randstr4.tar.gz
│   ├── randstr5.randstr6.tar.gz
│   ├── randstr7.ext2
│   └── randstr8.ext3

There are x3 possible file extensions: .tar.gz and .ext1 and .ext2. Everywhere I have written randstr is a random string, and cannot be known in advance. There is only one file of each of the type .ext1 and .ext2, but there will be many (unknown in advance) of the type .tar.gz.
I need a way to raise a flag if any of the files are missing. I need a way to confirm that there is at least one file of each of the three extension types in this directory. I would like to do it with a loop if possible (to learn).
I tried it this way, but it doesn't seem to work:
error=false
# Loop over each of the three extensions, and check if a file exists
for ext in ext1 ext2 tar.gz; do
    filenames=( "main_dir"/*."$ext" )
    if [ "${#filenames[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
        error=true
        break
    fi
done

if "$error"; then
    echo 'One or more files missing' >&2
else
    echo "All files present"
fi

(I am using bash on Debian 12)

@ChrisDavies Yes exactly. I do not need to check for an ext3. The purpose of the script is to check that a backup was performed successfully, so checking for the presence of the mentioned files is sufficient to be confident that the backup worked for me.

Loop across the extensions. Search for the first file matching the pattern. Error if none is found.
#!/bin/sh
#
dir=main_dir

missing=
for ext in tar.gz ext1 ext2
do
    if [ -z "$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.$ext" -print -quit)" ]
    then
        missing=1
        break
    fi
done
if [ "${missing:-0}" -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "Uh oh, missing at least one required file in '$dir'" >&2
fi

Replace missing=1 and break with missing=$((missing+1)) if you'd like to know how many extension types were missing. You could also collect the missing extension types in an string  (or array, if you were using a shell such as bash that supported them) for later reference. Lots of options here depending on what you want to achieve from the check process.
Your own code is close - assuming it's running under an array-capable shell such as bash. There are a couple of reasons why it's not working. The first is that in your example data you have main_dir but in your code you reference maindir. The second and more likely reason is that you're falling foul of the fact that (by default) using a wildcard pattern that doesn't match anything will return itself. So where you have "maindir"/*."$ext" and (say) ext=ext1, if there is no match you'll get back the literal string maindir/*.ext1 (including that asterisk). The result is that your arrest is never empty and so the count of elements is never zero. You can fix this in bash by setting shopt -s nullglob

Thanks Chris, I will test this solution and get back to you. Additionally, can you help me see what is wrong with my attempt?

@teeeeee answer updated

Switching to find only adds problems IMO here: (1) find "$dir" fails for values of $dir that start with - or are predicates (2) it doesn't skip hidden files (3) -quit is a non-portable extension, some have -exit instead, some have neither. Same for -maxdepth (4) many find/fnmatch() implementations choke on non-text filenames. (5) OP said nothing about restricting the match to regular files (6) running an external utility in an extra process and get its output through a pipe is likely more costly than letting the shell do it.

(7) you need -H in case $dir is a symlink to a directory. if you remove the (unrequested) -type f, $dir may be counted itself, if it ends in one of those extensions, generally it's find -H "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 or its standard find "$dir/." ! -name . -prune equivalent you need if you only want the files at depth 1.

With zsh instead of bash:
if ()(( $# == 3 )) main_dir/*.{ext1,ext2,tar.gz}(NY1); then
  print At least one non-hidden file of each extension exists
fi

Or with the list of extensions in an array:
ext=(ext1 ext2 tar.gz)
if ()(( $# == $#ext )) main_dir/*.$^ext(NY1); then
  print At least one non-hidden file of each extension exists
fi

Add the D qualifier to also consider hidden files (like find would), but then you may want to change the * in the pattern to ?* as a file called .ext1 for instance is generally considered as a hidden file without extension rather than a ext1 file with an empty root name.
Add . to restrict to regular files (to the exclusion of all other types of files such as fifos, symlinks, directories, like -type f) or -. for that check to be done after symlink resolution (like GNU find's -xtype f).
With the Y1 glob qualifier, zsh doesn't sort the list of file and stops looking after the 1st matching file. We still look for the 3 extensions even if no file was found for the first. For very large directories, it may be beneficial to rewrite it has:
has_all_extensions() {
  local dir=$1 ext; shift
  for ext do
    ()(( $# )) $dir/*.$ext(NY1) || return
  done
}
if has_all_extensions main_dir ext1 ext2 tar.gz
  print At least one non-hidden file of each extension exists
fi

Your approach would work in bash if you added shopt -s nullglob; shopt -u failglob as the equivalent of zsh's N glob qualifier for the globs to expand to nothing instead of themselves or of causing an error with failglob or zsh (and replaced maindir with main_dir though I suppose that's just a typo in the question). bash has no equivalent for zsh's Y1 or ./-. qualifiers though. bash 5.3 has GLOBSORT=none to disable the sorting of glob expansions.
